# centering Masonry item in a column

Tags: css, masonry

I have a problem with Masonry v3.1.2.
I would like to have some of the thumbnails smaller than the others on my layout.

I have set the maximum width of the column to 400px but sometimes i’d like to have some images smaller, (i.e. 300px)

Currently images align to the left side, but I would like them to be centred in the column.
How can I center the smaller images in the center of the column?

This is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
      itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 350,
        "isFitWidth": true
    });
</script>

<div id="mansory-container"  data-masonry-options='{}'>
    <div class="item center">
        <a href="<?=base_url()?>projects_detail/<?=$row->documents_url?>">
            <img src="example.jpg" alt="my image" class="documents-image" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#mansory-container{max-width:950% !important;}
.item{max-width:350px !important;margin:20px auto !important;/*position:relative !important;*/}
.documents-image{/*max-width:350px;*/}      
</style>
```

Comment: Is this your entire code? There's no mention of setting the "maximum width of the column to 400px"

Comment: right, sorry. this is the previous version. now is     var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
      itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 400,
        "isFitWidth": true
    });

Answer (score 0):

You need to center the container like this:

```
#mansory-container{
  max-width:950% !important;
  margin: 0 auto; // <-- added
}
```

[Here's a codepen showing it works](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOKOVe)